# "Normal" $p$-adic Numbers?

Tags: soft-question, p-adic-number-theory

We say that a real number $x$ is *normal* in base $b$ if every string of $n$ digits appears with density $b^{-n}$ in $x$'s base $b$ expansion. It seems like it would be easy to generalize this notion to $p$-adic numbers, say if every string of $n$ digits appears with density $p^{-n}$. I wanted to see what is known about the subject, but "normal $p$-adic numbers" isn't yielding anything. Is there a different term for this notion?

Comment: The same Borel-Cantelli argument as in the real case establishes that almost all $p$-adic numbers are normal. I'm not aware of any interesting consequences or applications of this.

Comment: Formatting the strings left to right instead of right to left doesn't really change any meaningful properties of the string.